# Injective, surjective or bijective.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider: $f : \{-1,0,1\} \to \{-1,0,1\}$ defined by $f(x) = x^2$.

I think this is surjective only because $f(-1) = f(1)$.

Am I right in thinking so, if not could you please tell me why.

Comment: No, it's not right. The fact that two inputs yield the same output means that it's not injective. But the fact that it's not injective doesn't mean it's surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injection:
$f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$

Injective functions are called 1-1 functions.

It is not injective as $f(-1) = f(1)$

Surjection:  For all $y$ in the codomain, there exists an $x$ in the domain such that $f(x) = y$

A sujective function is sometimes called "onto" as it maps onto every element in the co-domain.

It is not surjective as there is no $x$ that maps to $-1$

Bijection requires both injection and surjection.

Comment: If it isn't injective or surjective, then what is it?

Comment: It is just a function.  It has no special type.  There is not a name for this.

Comment: The professor must've made a mistake then..

Comment: Thank you for your answer though, really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you see $f(-1)=f(1)$, the right conclusion should be it is not injective.

As for the question of whether it is no surjective, think of what is the preimage of element in the codomain, if you can always find a preimage, then it is surjective. Otherwise, it is not surjective.